# Cucumber: How do I use Multiple Scenario Outlines with one Example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

```
Scenario Outline:
   blah blah

Scenarios:
 | col | col |
 | dat | dat |

Scenario Outline
  blah blah
  <use first scenarios table>
```

is ther a way to do this? I'd hate to have to copy a table... =\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you use shouldn't depend on the scenario, so it's no big deal if you copy/paste the data from one scenario to the next. I know this isn't DRY - so if you're copying the data more than a couple of times, consider using a Factory instead (see #2).

That being said, there's a couple of things you can do/questions to ask:

1. If `blah blah` is implemented as a step definition, then it's assumed that you'll reuse it when needed, that's partly what it's for
2. Your col/dat table might be able to be replaced with a Factory (via FactoryGirl). It's pretty common to use FactoryGirl as part of your testing, alongside Cucumber.

Comment: do you have an example of how to use Factory Girl in this sense? Like... this is how I'm using the tables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614818/running-a-login-step-prior-to-scenario-outline-in-cucumber

Comment: Well, that's not something I can answer in a short form. So, I will simply point you to this RailsCast, which shows you how to create Factories, with multiple examples: http://railscasts.com/episodes/158-factories-not-fixtures

Comment: aye, those factories are for madels though, aren't they? The table I have is a permissions table.... so a factory might not be the ideal way to go about this problem. =\ idk