# Defining Examples for multiple Scenario Outlines

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

In a project where we're using cucumber-jvm for our webtests, I've come across a problem which so far I haven't been able to solve: Se have several `Scenario Outline`s which should all use the same `Examples`. Now, of course I can copy these examples to every single one, but it would be much shorter (and probably easier to understand) if you could do something like this:

```
Background:
  Examples:
    | name  |
    | Alice |
    | Bob   |

Scenario Outline: Flying to the conference
  Given I'm flying to a confernce
  When I try to check in at the airport
  And my name is <name>
  Then I should get my plane ticket

Scenario Outline: Collecting the conference ticket
  Given I'm at a conference
  When I ask for the ticket for <name>
  And show my business card to prove my id
  Then I should get my conference ticket

Scenario Outline: Collectiong my personalized swag bag
  Given I'm at a conference
  When I go to the first booth
  And show them my conference ticket with the name <name>
  Then they'll give me a swag bag with the name <name> printed onto it
```

Is something like that possible? If so, how? Would I use some kind of factory as is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362372/cucumber-how-do-i-use-multiple-scenario-outlines-with-one-example)? If so, any recomendations?

Comment: do you need to run this whole feature two times, one time with alice and one time with bob, or can u make use of a list of names in the needed steps?

Comment: @Dude The idea is running the whole feature with every name.

Comment: What would be the added benefit of running all scenarios with all users? Why not mix and match (run some with one user and some with another). If All scenarios should pass for both user Bob and Alice, what are you really testing by running one scenario for two users?

Comment: It depends on the situation of course; while I don't remember the specific situation from when I asked the question, a possible reason would be that certain scenarios should play out the same for different users who have different values in certain databases assigned to them. In the above example, maybe I want to make sure that women and men are treated equally. Or that age doesn't change the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you combined the three scenarios into one scenario then what you want to achieve is trivial.  Breaking them out into separate scenarios allows

- Each to run (and fail) independently
- Have a separate line in the report

If you are willing to forgo the former and combine the three into one scenario then I can suggest a solution that supports the latter. Cucumber-jvm does support the ability to write text into a report in an [(After) hook via the Scenario object](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/e471442b0bd6a6d263bbcac03c8079107a36d84d/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/Scenario.java).  In your step definition class define as a class variable

```
private List<String> stepStatusList;
```

You can initialize it in the step definition's class constructor.

```
this.stepStatusList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In the last step of each of the formally three scenarios add text into stepStatusList with the status that you want to appear in the report.

```
this.stepStatusList.add("Scenario sub-part identifier, some status");
```

In the After hook, write the lines into the report. This sample assumes that you want to write the lines independently of the success or failure of the scenario.

```
@Before
public void setup_cucumber_spring_context(){
    // Dummy method so cucumber will recognize this class as glue
    // and use its context configuration.
}

@After
public void captureScreenshotOnFailure(Scenario scenario) {

    // write scenario-part status into the report
    for (String substatus : this.stepStatusList) {
        scenario.write(substatus);
    }

    // On scenario failure, add a screenshot to the cucumber report
    if (scenario.isFailed() && webDriver != null) { 

        try {
            WebDriver augemented = new Augmenter().augment(webDriver);
            byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) augemented).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);

            scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```